# JQuery rcarousel duplicates slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used the rcarousel plugin a couple of times without encountering any problem.

While implementing it on a new website, rcarousel suddenly **duplicates** the first slide (I'm showing 3).

This is happening on both slides on the bottom of this page:

http://www.expertmarketermagazine.com/en/home

When you navigate the slider you can see that the "duplicate" reverts to the correct slide just before the whole thing slides away.

Has anyone encountered something similar before?

Comment: If you setup a minimal example with **just** the rcarousel, does it still do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your rcarousel selectors to:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#carousel-authors .wrapper").rcarousel({
            visible: 3,
            step: 3,
            width: 127,
            height: 200,
            navigation: {
                prev: "#ui-carousel-next-authors",
                next: "#ui-carousel-prev-authors"
            }
        });

        $("#carousel-books .wrapper").rcarousel({
            visible: 3,
            step: 3,
            width: 127,
            height: 200,
            navigation: {
                prev: "#ui-carousel-next-books",
                next: "#ui-carousel-prev-books"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This messes up the automated markup. I've actually implemented rcarousel before in exactly the same way - that's why I'm puzzled about this strange duplication behavior

Comment: then at least remove the wrapping <div class="wrapper" />, take a look at: http://tinkerbin.com/6GTkWHbm

Note: you have to re-hit "run" to get a correct result

Comment: You're right, simply removing the wrapper did the trick. Still don't understand why rcarousel behaved as it did because of it though. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! rcarousel seems to generate the wrapping <div class="wrapper" /> on the fly - take a look via firebug

Comment: Exactly so, rcarousel creates a wrapper div (with the class "wrapper") and addresses it in its selectors. In this respect it's surprising that the slider did work aside from the duplication.